# Duplicate TAG related to the Android component "BroadcastReceiver"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

I found three tags that refer to the same concept.

It the Android component: [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html), and the tags are:

[android-broadcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-broadcast)
[broadcastreceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/broadcastreceiver)
[android-broadcastreceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-broadcastreceiver)

Probably should be fine to merge them in just one tag.

Answer (score 3):

Although I agree with [broadcastreceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/broadcastreceiver) being merged into [android-broadcastreceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-broadcastreceiver). [android-broadcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-broadcast) has a slightly different meaning.

[android-broadcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-broadcast) is interpretted more as the *sending* of a broadcast, as opposed to the receiving.

The description for [android-broadcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-broadcast) explains it quite well:

> A broadcast intent on the Android platform is a special intent which
>   is often invoked by the system on an event and catched by a
>   BroadcastReceiver.

Whereas the description for [android-broadcastreceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-broadcastreceiver):

> BroadcastReceiver is an Android component that responds to system-wide
>   broadcast announcements.

Comment: I think it is a good observation. Probably it makes sense change [tag:android-broadcast] into [tag:android-broadcast-intent]